# Как оформить вопрос, если это не прямая речь?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, тире-или-двоеточие, вопрос

Как следует оформить вопрос, если это не прямая речь?

*О высокотехнологичном сценарии развития человечества написано многое, но главный вопрос – какое в этом будущее место отведено человеку?*

Верно ли поставлено тире или вместо него нужно двоеточие?
Мой вопрос касается именно такого построения предложения.

Answer (score 0):

По слуху здесь тире как **однозначный вариант** (нет **интонационного предупреждения** по Розенталю, характерного для двоеточия):

*О высокотехнологичном сценарии развития человечества написано **мнОгое, но глАвный** вопрос – **какое место в этом будущем отведено человеку?***

Сравнить: *О высокотехнологичном сценарии развития человечества написано многое, но главный вопрос всегда **такой:** **какое место в этом будущем отведено человеку?***

**Как объяснить?** Можно считать, что в позиции **сказуемого**  находится вопросительное предложение после подлежащего "главный вопрос". Другой вариант объяснения – выбор тире в ***БСП*** (в первой части номинативная конструкция "главный вопрос" ).

**Пример:**

*Теперь же у нас остался **глАвный** вопрос – **почему всё возникло?*** (Евгений Плисов, Научное мировоззрение изменит вашу жизнь. Почему мы изучаем Вселенную и как это помогает нам понять самих себя?, 2020).

В этом случае возможен **выбор** (двоеточие или тире), что определяется по **контексту**.

Answer (score 0):

• Сначала "отрегулируем" сам вопрос, потому что в нём имеется **ошибка**.

*Какое в этом будущее место отведено человеку?*
Правильно, думаю, так: *Какое* [в чём?] *в этом **будущем** место отведено человеку?*
Или так: *Какое **в нём*** [в сценарии] *место отведено человеку?*

•• Основное предложение (без вопроса), считаю, является незаконченным (не хватает глагола).
*О высокотехнологичном сценарии развития человечества написано многое, но главный вопрос.* [Вот тут он, глагол, должен быть.]

••• Я бы написала так (вопрос оформлен как вставка):
*О высокотехнологичном сценарии развития человечества написано многое, но главный вопрос — **какое в этом будущем место отведено человеку?** — остался без ответа.*

Или так (с двоеточием):
*О высокотехнологичном сценарии развития человечества написано многое, но главный вопрос остался:* [какой именно?] ***какое в нём место отведено человеку?***